# How to get class path in Python

Tags: python, django

In Python, we can define a class and print it as such:

```py
class a:
    num = 1

b = a()

print(b)
```

And we would get the output:

```py
<class '__main__.a'>
```

I'm trying to identify unique classes, and I have some classes with longer paths. I would like to extract the "class path", or `__main__.a` in the case above. For example, if I print some longer class I would get:

```py
<class 'django_seed.tests.Game'>
<class 'django_seed.tests.Player'>
<class 'django_seed.tests.Action'>
```

And I would like to extract:

```py
'django_seed.tests.Game'
'django_seed.tests.Player'
'django_seed.tests.Action'
```

Since I can cast `<class 'django_seed.tests.Game'>` to a string, I can substring it quite easily with `'<class 'django_seed.tests.Game'>'[8:-2]`, but I'm sure there must be a cleaner way. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `__module__` attribute can be used to access the "path" of a class (where it was defined) and the `__name__` attribute returns the name of the class as a string

```
print(f'{YourClass.__module__}.{YourClass.__name__}')
```

Comment: @ReinstateMonica If the class was defined in `__main__` then `cls.__module__` returns `__main__`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inspect`:

```
import inspect

print((inspect.getmodule(a).__file__))
```